# cannot execute binary file installing Miniconda

Tags: linux, bash, centos-7, anaconda

Im trying to install Miniconda on a server. I downloaded the .sh file from 
https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh

I ran the following:

```
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh
```

I received this message:

```
installing: python-3.7.1-h0371630_7 ...
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh: line 373: mydirectory/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.1-h0371630_7/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
```

Does anyone know what I could do to fix this?